# Error on SQL Server Insert stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to simply insert data into a table in SQL Server from a C# winforms application.

Currently when the executing the query I'm receiving the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'soAddItems'

Here is my `insert` code of the class handling my database CRUD operations:

Note: As test data:

- itemName = "test"
- skuNo = "a123"
- itemPrice = 2.99
- stockItemToAdd = 3
- itemPic = "C:\Users\Name\Pictures\pic.png"**

Code:

```
public virtual void AddItem(string itemName, string skuNo, double itemPrice, int stockAmountToAdd, string itemPic)
{
        using (SqlConnection open = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("soAddItems", open);

            open.Open();

            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@itemName", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = itemName;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@skuNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = skuNo;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@itemPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = itemPrice;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@instockAmount", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = stockAmountToAdd;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@lastSold", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Today;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@itemPic", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = itemPic;

            //***** Error on the execute*****
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        };
    }
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[soAddItems]
   @itemName nchar,
   @skuNo varchar,
   @itemPrice float,
   @instockAmount bigint,
   @lastSold dateTime, 
   @itemPic varchar
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO items (itemName, skuNo, itemPrice, instockAmount, lastSold, itemPic) 
    VALUES (@itemName, @skuNo, @itemPrice, @instockAmount, @itemPic)
END
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your command type should be StoredProcedure, no? Also, [why are your nchar and varchar parameters not specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the `SqlCommand` command type as stored procedure.

Try this:

```
insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forget to assign your [`SqlCommand.CommandType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Because it is [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a default.

```
insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the missing `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, you have a second major flaw: if you define a parameter like this: `@skuNo varchar` - then you get a string of **1 character length**!

That's usually not what you want - you should **ALWAYS** specify a length when defining parameters and variables in T-SQL!

Use: `@skuNo varchar(50)` or whatever length you need

Comment: Its funny you should say that marc as I was just trying to work out why my image path was being set to 1 character! Many thanks for this, I'm pretty new to SQL server.